# Possible to change SPO outgoing email address?

Tags: email, outgoing-email, spo

I would like to change the "From" email address of SharePoint Online.

That is I want to change no-reply@microsoft.com with someother email address for SP Online notifications.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

No, this isn't possible as this value is set by Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question as well with SharePoint Workflows.  After researching and not finding a solution, I re-wrote my WorkFlow to a MS Flow and made a connector with the email address I wanted to use for that Specific Flow Step.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/use-connectors-to-configure-mail-flow/use-connectors-to-configure-mail-flow